# How to set the value of a string attribute within a dll via a console application

Tags: c#, string, dll, console

I have a dll which contains as string as follows:

```
[Display(GroupName = "Test", Name = "String")]
public string String { get; } //Shows content of string in an UI (readonly)
```

Now I want determine the content of the String via a second application (e.g. console application) which opens the dll and assigns a string "XYZ" according to the user input to that string, so that it will be hard coded from the moment of that change for the future in this dll.

Is that possible and if yes, any hints how this could be implemented ?

Comment: There are probably more sophisticated ways, but one would be to disassemble the assembly with ildasm - alter the resulting .il file - then reassemble it with ilasm.

Comment: Thx, I need a more "user friendly" approach becaus the one who is dealing with the second application is not a developer ;-). Would this be possibly by using refelction e.g. ?

Comment: Almost certainly, yes, but I haven't worked with that API in years, so I would not be a good tutor for that.